# Is the plural form of ID spelled ID's or ID?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

How to write or tell that collection of Email ID's has been attached.

Comment: It's ID's or IDs. AFAIK whether or not to use an apostrophe is solely a matter of preference. Both are valid.

Comment: Yes, it can depend on the style guide you're using, but since you're clearly not using a style guide, the plural of *cat* is *cats*, and the plural of *ID* is *IDs*. Simple as that. There is no reason to even consider an apostrophe. It conveys no additional information that the simple *-s* does not. As to "how to tell", what do you mean? They sound completely identical in speech. Lastly, there is no reason to tag this "grammaticality". The question is entirely about orthography and has nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 12):

It would be *IDs*. Were you to use the apostrophe (i.e, *ID's*), that would imply possession. If you're simply referring to a group of IDs, you drop the apostrophe.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no valid reason to put an apostrophe in IDs, as it is neither a possessive nor a contraction. It is simply a plural.